# JVM Crash - "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, jvm

Today I decided to continue working on a program that I had created for my Computer Science class. Upon running it, I am greeted with this in the console:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffeb23c7510, pid=7320, tid=9084
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007ffeb23c7510
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\CS PROGRAM FINAL\hs_err_pid7320.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

So, I try to run another program that is completely unrelated to the first one, and the same thing happens. Bear in mind that everything was working perfectly yesterday.

Then, I tried to install a fresh copy of eclipse (Luna) on and try the program again.

Running a simple "Hello World" program works perfectly, but once again, running the first program crashes the JVM with the same error.

I am running Java 1.8 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

The program that I cannot run simply uses AWT and Swing classes as well as some io classes such as BufferedWriter.

This is the log produced by eclipse:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffeb23c7510, pid=9044, tid=1944
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007ffeb23c7510
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001dfbc000):  JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1944, stack(0x000000001ed50000,0x000000001ee50000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x00007ffeb23c7510

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000021a57f20, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x000000001ee4e050, RDX=0x0000000021a53b48
RSP=0x000000001ee4e028, RBP=0x00000000210f8028, RSI=0x0000000021a53b40, RDI=0x0000000021a53b40
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x0000000020f10150, R11=0x00000000231a3a20
R12=0x0000000000000020, R13=0x0000000000000020, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x000000001dfbc000
RIP=0x00007ffeb23c7510, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001ee4e028)
0x000000001ee4e028:   00007ffeb21675d7 0000000000000008
0x000000001ee4e038:   000000002196ec80 0000000000000001
0x000000001ee4e048:   fffffffffffffffe 0000000021a53b40
0x000000001ee4e058:   0000000000000000 0000000000000001
0x000000001ee4e068:   00000000665f17a0 000000002196ec80
0x000000001ee4e078:   000000001df48030 00000000210f8028
0x000000001ee4e088:   0000000021a53b40 fffffffffffffffe
0x000000001ee4e098:   00000000666a57fe 0000000000000000
0x000000001ee4e0a8:   00007ffeb21677cc 0000000000000000
0x000000001ee4e0b8:   0000000000000008 fffffffffffffffe
0x000000001ee4e0c8:   00000000665ec30a 0000000000000000
0x000000001ee4e0d8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000001
0x000000001ee4e0e8:   0000000000000000 0000000021a53b40
0x000000001ee4e0f8:   00000000665e88f0 00000000210f7d90
0x000000001ee4e108:   00000000210f7d90 0000000000000000
0x000000001ee4e118:   0000000000000000 000056ad00000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffeb23c7510)
0x00007ffeb23c74f0:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000021a57f20 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001ee4e050 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001dfbc000
RDX=0x0000000021a53b48 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001ee4e028 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001dfbc000
RBP=0x00000000210f8028 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000021a53b40 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000021a53b40 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000020f10150 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000231a3a20 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000020 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000020 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000001dfbc000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001ed50000,0x000000001ee50000],  sp=0x000000001ee4e028,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00007ffeb23c7510

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsDevice.getDeviceCapsNative(I)I+0
j  sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsDevice.access$000(I)I+1
j  sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsDevice$1.run()V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop()V+0
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run()V+58
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000002080800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=7952, stack(0x0000000001f10000,0x0000000002010000)]
  0x000000001dfbe000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=8420, stack(0x000000001f0f0000,0x000000001f1f0000)]
=>0x000000001dfbc000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1944, stack(0x000000001ed50000,0x000000001ee50000)]
  0x000000001dfb7800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=8836, stack(0x000000001ec50000,0x000000001ed50000)]
  0x000000001df74800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7760, stack(0x000000001eb50000,0x000000001ec50000)]
  0x000000001dc90000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7300, stack(0x000000001e5d0000,0x000000001e6d0000)]
  0x000000001dc16000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8408, stack(0x000000001e4d0000,0x000000001e5d0000)]
  0x000000001dc02800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5008, stack(0x000000001e3d0000,0x000000001e4d0000)]
  0x000000001dbfb800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4868, stack(0x000000001e2d0000,0x000000001e3d0000)]
  0x000000001dbf5800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8548, stack(0x000000001e1d0000,0x000000001e2d0000)]
  0x000000001dbf4000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8580, stack(0x000000001e0d0000,0x000000001e1d0000)]
  0x000000001bbee000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=952, stack(0x000000001dfd0000,0x000000001e0d0000)]
  0x0000000002176000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6040, stack(0x000000001dad0000,0x000000001dbd0000)]
  0x000000001bbdc000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7336, stack(0x000000001d9d0000,0x000000001dad0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001bbd7000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001d8d0000,0x000000001d9d0000] [id=8528]
  0x000000001dc92000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001e6d0000,0x000000001e7d0000] [id=8996]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 560K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b380000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 12% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b190390,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 96% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b27c010,0x000000076b280000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b300000,0x000000076b300000,0x000000076b380000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 124K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c141f010,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 5180K, capacity 5314K, committed 5632K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 642K, capacity 692K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011540000,0x0000000011d40000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000df36000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000065c612b0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012a90000, 0x0000000016a40000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000016a40000, 0x000000001a9f0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000720000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1436Kb max_used=1436Kb free=244323Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002180000, 0x00000000023f0000, 0x0000000011180000]
 total_blobs=498 nmethods=178 adapters=234
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.176 Thread 0x000000001dc16000  173       3       java.lang.String::indexOf (166 bytes)
Event: 0.176 Thread 0x000000001dc16000 nmethod 173 0x00000000022e2650 code [0x00000000022e2800, 0x00000000022e2e50]
Event: 0.176 Thread 0x000000001dc16000  174       3       jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Type::getType (269 bytes)
Event: 0.176 Thread 0x000000001dc16000 nmethod 174 0x00000000022e3210 code [0x00000000022e3400, 0x00000000022e3cd0]
Event: 0.176 Thread 0x000000001dc16000  176       3       sun.invoke.util.Wrapper::hashChar (9 bytes)
Event: 0.176 Thread 0x000000001dc16000 nmethod 176 0x00000000022e40d0 code [0x00000000022e4220, 0x00000000022e4370]
Event: 0.180 Thread 0x000000001dc16000  177       3       java.util.HashMap::putVal (300 bytes)
Event: 0.181 Thread 0x000000001dc16000 nmethod 177 0x00000000022e4650 code [0x00000000022e48c0, 0x00000000022e5b98]
Event: 0.181 Thread 0x000000001dc16000  178       3       java.util.HashMap::put (13 bytes)
Event: 0.181 Thread 0x000000001dc16000 nmethod 178 0x00000000022e6250 code [0x00000000022e63e0, 0x00000000022e6798]

GC Heap History (6 events):
Event: 0.072 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 512K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 100% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b300000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b280000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 0K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 3127K, capacity 4522K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 378K, capacity 418K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 0.072 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 496K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 96% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b27c010,0x000000076b280000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b300000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 8K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c1402000,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 3127K, capacity 4522K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 378K, capacity 418K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 0.110 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 1008K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 100% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 96% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b27c010,0x000000076b280000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b300000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 8K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c1402000,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 4604K, capacity 4724K, committed 4992K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 555K, capacity 601K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 0.111 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 496K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b380000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 96% used [0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b2fc010,0x000000076b300000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b280000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 76K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c1413010,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 4604K, capacity 4724K, committed 4992K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 555K, capacity 601K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 0.178 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 1008K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b380000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 100% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 96% used [0x000000076b280000,0x000000076b2fc010,0x000000076b300000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b280000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 76K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c1413010,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 4956K, capacity 5026K, committed 5376K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 614K, capacity 660K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 0.179 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 496K [0x000000076b180000, 0x000000076b380000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b180000,0x000000076b200000)
  from space 512K, 96% used [0x000000076b200000,0x000000076b27c010,0x000000076b280000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x000000076b300000,0x000000076b300000,0x000000076b380000)
 ParOldGen       total 260608K, used 124K [0x00000006c1400000, 0x00000006d1280000, 0x000000076b180000)
  object space 260608K, 0% used [0x00000006c1400000,0x00000006c141f010,0x00000006d1280000)
 Metaspace       used 4956K, capacity 5026K, committed 5376K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 614K, capacity 660K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.075 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b18a008) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 0.077 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b18c030) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 0.077 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b18d238) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000076b191668) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 716]
Event: 0.085 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b19bbf0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': java/lang/Null> (0x000000076b1c0b90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 202]
Event: 0.113 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x000000076b198ed0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1159]
Event: 0.115 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x000000076b1a7aa8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1159]
Event: 0.116 Thread 0x0000000002080800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x000000076b1ab3c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1159]
Event: 0.183 Thread 0x000000001dfbe000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000076b18db60) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u11\648\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 716]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/pipe/RenderQueue done
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DRenderQueue done
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/pipe/RenderBuffer
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/pipe/RenderBuffer done
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DRenderQueue$1
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DRenderQueue$1 done
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DGraphicsDevice$1Result
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DGraphicsDevice$1Result done
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DGraphicsDevice$1
Event: 0.199 loading class sun/java2d/d3d/D3DGraphicsDevice$1 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7fe8b0000 - 0x00007ff7fe8e4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ffec5e40000 - 0x00007ffec5fea000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffec55e0000 - 0x00007ffec571a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffec32d0000 - 0x00007ffec33df000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffec13b0000 - 0x00007ffec1438000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffeb9ee0000 - 0x00007ffeb9f2f000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ffec5140000 - 0x00007ffec51e7000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffec2ff0000 - 0x00007ffec301b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffec3800000 - 0x00007ffec3851000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffec4f60000 - 0x00007ffec50d1000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffec5b80000 - 0x00007ffec5cf8000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffec3860000 - 0x00007ffec4c80000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffec24d0000 - 0x00007ffec24ee000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffec58f0000 - 0x00007ffec5995000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffebcc70000 - 0x00007ffebcc8b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffec36c0000 - 0x00007ffec37f7000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffec5890000 - 0x00007ffec58e7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffec59a0000 - 0x00007ffec5b76000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ffec5390000 - 0x00007ffec54d4000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffec31b0000 - 0x00007ffec31c4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffec2150000 - 0x00007ffec21ef000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffec55a0000 - 0x00007ffec55d4000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffec5d00000 - 0x00007ffec5e39000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffec2720000 - 0x00007ffec297a000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17031_none_6242a4b3ecbb55a1\COMCTL32.dll
0x00000000667d0000 - 0x00000000668a2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000654b0000 - 0x0000000065cda000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffec1cc0000 - 0x00007ffec1cc9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffebbf40000 - 0x00007ffebbf5f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffec4c80000 - 0x00007ffec4c87000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffec5830000 - 0x00007ffec5888000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffebbf10000 - 0x00007ffebbf3a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffec5720000 - 0x00007ffec5729000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffec3670000 - 0x00007ffec36ba000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffec1600000 - 0x00007ffec1626000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00000000667c0000 - 0x00000000667cf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000066790000 - 0x00000000667b8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.dll
0x0000000066770000 - 0x0000000066786000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\zip.dll
0x00000000665d0000 - 0x0000000066766000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\awt.dll
0x00007ffec54e0000 - 0x00007ffec5597000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffec1480000 - 0x00007ffec15a1000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x000000018006b000     C:\Program Files (x86)\RivaTuner Statistics Server\RTSSHooks64.dll
0x00000000683d0000 - 0x0000000068473000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_08e793bfa83a89b5\MSVCR90.dll
0x00007ffebfcd0000 - 0x00007ffebfcf0000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ffec13a0000 - 0x00007ffec13aa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffec3080000 - 0x00007ffec308a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00007ffec3020000 - 0x00007ffec3080000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffeb2140000 - 0x00007ffeb2348000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x00007ffec18f0000 - 0x00007ffec18fa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffec08b0000 - 0x00007ffec09fb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\aticfx64.dll
0x00007ffeb9080000 - 0x00007ffeb90a1000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atiu9p64.dll
0x00007ffeb14c0000 - 0x00007ffeb1c61000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atiumd64.dll
0x0000000066db0000 - 0x00000000674e7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atiumd6a.dll
0x00007ffeb3720000 - 0x00007ffeb38a8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\CS PROGRAM FINAL\bin
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javaw.exe;C:\Python34\;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;
USERNAME=Adam
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 62 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 16689944k(13276820k free), swap 33073944k(28367744k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_11-b12), built on Jun 16 2014 20:57:32 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Aug 20 14:55:53 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Could this be a hardware problem?

Comment: Change your workspace. Don't copy and paste anything from old one

Comment: @MindPeace Thanks for replying, unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work. It gives the same error as before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The crash happens inside DirectX library: `d3d9.dll`. Try the following options:

- Update / reinstall graphics driver.
- Switch off graphics card utilities (I've noticed RivaTuner in the list of loaded libraries).
- Run Java with `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` JVM option or set `J2D_D3D=false` environment variable. This would definitely help, though Java will not make use of Direct3D acceleration.

Comment: You were right. It seems that MSI Afterburner is the cause for this crash (I disabled RivaTuner on its own but that did not do anything) Thank you!

Comment: How did you conclude the issue was with d3d9.dll ?

Comment: @BryanHarrington Since PC points to an invalid address, the closest frame should be retrieved from the stack. Top of stack usually holds the return address on a call. In this case it is `00007ffeb21675d7`, which lies in the range of `0x00007ffeb2140000 - 0x00007ffeb2348000` belonging to `C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll` (see dynamic libraries section).

Comment: Same problem here, in my case with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION VBoxD3D9wddm.dll. Adding the argument to java run solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: J2D_D3D helped. Thanks!

Comment: @apangin : How did you determined that crash happen in d3d9.dll?

Comment: @GauravJeswani Look above

Comment: Thanks sorry I missed that part. Could you please hemp me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297466/jvm-crashes-with-exception-access-violation-ntdll-dll0x1b96f

Comment: @apangin How were you able to find the address range corresponding to a particular dll?

Comment: @vsriram92 From "Dynamic libraries" section in hs_err.log

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. I was using Java version 1.6 update 45. And project requirement was Java 1.6 
I downgraded the version from 1.6 update 45 to 1.6 update 38. It worked for me.
Hope this works for you, in case if you have specific Java requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Running on windows 10, changing from java version 1.8.0_121 to 1.8.0_231 resolved the error for me.

Comment: This works for me, when install `weblogic`, after install there's config process, assign jdk version to `1.8` folder path in the setting page, and set system env `JAVA_HOME` to `1.8` folder path, then weblogic deploy works without error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in spring tools suite 4.6.2 using java 9--reverting to java 1.8 resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 11, the issue appeared once i installed some new windows updates. I solved it by running the tool in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the answers but nothing worked in my case.

Eventually it turned out to be a permission issue on the C:\drive .

So basically `Program Files\Java` was not having rights on that user who calls the applet. However when ran with the administrator profile it worked.