# JVM crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION ntdll.dll+0x1b96f

Tags: java, dll, crash, jvm, fantom

I am running a Java application, but randomly it crashes my **JVM**. I have gone through multiple articles on this problem, but not able to find how I can debug/fix issue.

**Java Version:**

java version "`1.8.0_221`"

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

**Windows Version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit

**Logs from Windows Event Viewer:**

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 8.0.2210.11, time stamp: 0x5d1dea24
    Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17134.799, time stamp: 0x7f828745
    Exception code: 0xc0000374
    Fault offset: 0x00000000000f479b
    Faulting process id: 0xe2fc
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d57e559c68fca8
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    Report Id: 81304818-1e10-4181-a6cb-a07f8ff64f9f
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Logs from Application:**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8e314b96f, pid=46668, tid=0x000000000000d278
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_221-b11) (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.221-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x1b96f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000177a8000):  JavaThread "SysMod-Worker-28" [_thread_in_native, id=53880, stack(0x0000000027b20000,0x0000000027c20000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000024

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x000000006f931800, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x0000000027c1de90, RBP=0x0000000000716ae0, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00000000006a0000
R8 =0x0000000000716af0, R9 =0x0000000027c1e040, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000246
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000000100080
RIP=0x00007ff8e314b96f, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000027c1de90)
0x0000000027c1de90:   0000000000000001 0000000000716af0
0x0000000027c1dea0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000027c1deb0:   0000000000000101 0000000000000000
0x0000000027c1dec0:   0000000000100080 0000000000000000
0x0000000027c1ded0:   0000000000000000 00007ff864e37786

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff8e314b96f)
0x00007ff8e314b94f:   4d 08 33 0d 01 1b 14 00 33 cf 66 85 c9 0f 85 e1
0x00007ff8e314b95f:   fa 08 00 48 c1 e9 0c 48 8b c5 48 2b c1 48 8b 00
0x00007ff8e314b96f:   44 0f b7 40 24 0f b6 4d 0f 80 f9 05 0f 84 d4 fa
0x00007ff8e314b97f:   08 00 f6 c1 40 0f 85 de fa 08 00 0f b6 c1 24 3f 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000006f931800 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000027c1de90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000177a8000
RBP=0x0000000000716ae0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000006a0000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000716af0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000027c1e040 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000177a8000
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000246 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000100080 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000027b20000,0x0000000027c20000],  sp=0x0000000027c1de90,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x1b96f]
C  [AcLayers.DLL+0x7786]
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x34c18]
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x345b3]
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x36130]
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x3724f]
C  [nio.dll+0x5de9]
C  0x0000000002508c67

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetVolumePathName0(J)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetVolumePathName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+9
j  sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileStore.createFromPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/nio/fs/WindowsFileStore;+1
j  sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileStore.create(Lsun/nio/fs/WindowsPath;)Lsun/nio/fs/WindowsFileStore;+31
j  sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/nio/file/FileStore;+31
j  java.nio.file.Files.getFileStore(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/nio/file/FileStore;+5
j  fan.sys.LocalFile.store()Lfan/sys/FileStore;+11
j  fan.skyarcd.WatchdogMod.availSpace()Ljava/lang/Long;+7
j  fan.skyarcd.WatchdogMod.checkDisk()V+1
j  fan.skyarcd.WatchdogMod.onHouseKeeping()V+1
j  fan.skyarcd.SysMod.onReceive(Lfan/skyarcd/SysModMsg;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  fan.skyarcd.SysModActor.receive(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+16
J 4341 C2 fan.concurrent.Actor._work()V (163 bytes) @ 0x000000000341c1b0 [0x000000000341bf40+0x270]
j  fan.concurrent.ThreadPool$Worker.run()V+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000017d4b000 JavaThread "SysMod-Worker-30" [_thread_blocked, id=52960, stack(0x0000000029520000,0x0000000029620000)]
  0x0000000017d49000 JavaThread "ActorPool-Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=53620, stack(0x0000000029420000,0x0000000029520000)]
  0x000000001745f800 JavaThread "demo-ExtPool-Worker-19" [_thread_blocked, id=42624, stack(0x0000000029320000,0x0000000029420000)]
  0x0000000017464000 JavaThread "demo-ExtPool-Worker-18" [_thread_blocked, id=50544, stack(0x0000000029220000,0x0000000029320000)]
  0x0000000017467800 JavaThread "demo-Bacnet-Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=53192, stack(0x0000000028a20000,0x0000000028b20000)]
  0x0000000017463000 JavaThread "demo-PointPool-Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=53608, stack(0x0000000028820000,0x0000000028920000)]
  0x0000000019112800 JavaThread "demo-ControlEngine-Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4424, stack(0x0000000028520000,0x0000000028620000)]
  0x00000000177a2000 JavaThread "WispService-Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=48132, stack(0x0000000028120000,0x0000000028220000)]
  0x0000000017d4d800 JavaThread "WispService-Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=48876, stack(0x0000000027e20000,0x0000000027f20000)]
=>0x00000000177a8000 JavaThread "SysMod-Worker-28" [_thread_in_native, id=53880, stack(0x0000000027b20000,0x0000000027c20000)]
  0x00000000177aa000 JavaThread "demo-Bacnet-Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=50332, stack(0x0000000027420000,0x0000000027520000)]
  0x00000000177a0800 JavaThread "WispServiceSessions-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=53944, stack(0x0000000026920000,0x0000000026a20000)]
  0x0000000018e33000 JavaThread "WispServiceListener-Worker-0" [_thread_in_native, id=53748, stack(0x0000000026820000,0x0000000026920000)]
  0x0000000018e30800 JavaThread "demo-Haystack-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=12244, stack(0x0000000026520000,0x0000000026620000)]
  0x0000000017469000 JavaThread "demo-Bacnet-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=45000, stack(0x0000000026420000,0x0000000026520000)]
  0x000000001746d800 JavaThread "demo-Haystack-Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=53996, stack(0x0000000026320000,0x0000000026420000)]
  0x000000001746d000 JavaThread "demo-PointPool-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=51520, stack(0x0000000026220000,0x0000000026320000)]
  0x000000001746a800 JavaThread "Proj-demo-Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=32248, stack(0x0000000025f20000,0x0000000026020000)]
  0x000000001746b800 JavaThread "demo-Bacnet-Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=52496, stack(0x0000000025e20000,0x0000000025f20000)]
  0x0000000017d53800 JavaThread "demo-PointPool-Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=11632, stack(0x0000000024c20000,0x0000000024d20000)]
  0x0000000017d56800 JavaThread "demo-ControlEngine-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=50608, stack(0x0000000024b20000,0x0000000024c20000)]
  0x0000000017d4f000 JavaThread "ActorPool-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=53412, stack(0x0000000024220000,0x0000000024320000)]
  0x0000000018e35000 JavaThread "demo-ExtPool-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=47348, stack(0x0000000023420000,0x0000000023520000)]
  0x0000000018e2d000 JavaThread "Proj-demo-Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, 

Other Threads:
  0x0000000013d74000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000015e40000,0x0000000015f40000] [id=53512]
  0x00000000151d2800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000016940000,0x0000000016a40000] [id=49724]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x00000000e0000000, size: 512 MB, Compressed Oops mode: 32-bit
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000100000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 118272K, used 50380K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000ffb80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 66560K, 75% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f86b32f8,0x00000000f9680000)
  from space 51712K, 0% used [0x00000000f9680000,0x00000000f9680000,0x00000000fc900000)
  to   space 50176K, 0% used [0x00000000fca80000,0x00000000fca80000,0x00000000ffb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 113250K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 349696K, 32% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e6e98970,0x00000000f5580000)
 Metaspace       used 36487K, capacity 40998K, committed 41256K, reserved 1083392K
  class space    used 4988K, capacity 6357K, committed 6448K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000118b0000,0x00000000119c0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000111b0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00000000711d5ce0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012270000, 0x0000000012a70000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000012a70000, 0x0000000013270000)

Polling page: 0x00000000022b0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=19324Kb max_used=19409Kb free=226435Kb
 bounds [0x00000000024f0000, 0x0000000003800000, 0x00000000114f0000]
 total_blobs=5070 nmethods=4602 adapters=380
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 55.347 Thread 0x000000001516d000 nmethod 5833 0x00000000037f7f10 code [0x00000000037f81a0, 0x00000000037f9a08]
Event: 55.366 Thread 0x0000000015153800 nmethod 5832 0x00000000035a50d0 code [0x00000000035a5420, 0x00000000035a7e28]
Event: 55.749 Thread 0x000000001519d800 5834       3       fan.sys.DateTime::compare (36 bytes)
Event: 55.749 Thread 0x000000001519d800 nmethod 5834 0x000000000262f350 code [0x000000000262f4c0, 0x000000000262f7d0]
Event: 56.325 Thread 0x0000000015146000 5835       4       java.util.TimSort::mergeLo (659 bytes)
Event: 56.358 Thread 0x0000000015146000 nmethod 5835 0x0000000003151750 code [0x0000000003151900, 0x0000000003153158]
Event: 56.468 Thread 0x000000001516d000 5836       4       java.lang.String::trim (77 bytes)
Event: 56.468 Thread 0x000000001519d800 5837       3       fan.sys.MemBuf$MemBufOutStream::w (93 bytes)
Event: 56.469 Thread 0x000000001519d800 nmethod 5837 0x0000000002fa3650 code [0x0000000002fa37c0, 0x0000000002fa3aa8]
Event: 56.473 Thread 0x000000001516d000 nmethod 5836 0x00000000035dd210 code [0x00000000035dd380, 0x00000000035dd878]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 41.176 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 90624K, used 90494K [0x00000000f5580000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 67072K, 100% used [0x00000000f5580000,0x00000000f9700000,0x00000000f9700000)
  from space 23552K, 99% used [0x00000000f9700000,0x00000000faddf940,0x00000000fae00000)
  to   space 54784K, 0% used [0x00000000fca80000,0x00000000fca80000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 307712K, used 109148K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2c80000, 0x00000000f5580000)
  object space 307712K, 35% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e6a97038,0x00000000f2c80000)
 Metaspace       used 28919K, capacity 33304K, committed 33456K, reserved 1077248K
  class space    used 3923K, capacity 5259K, committed 5296K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 41.190 GC heap after

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 54.409 Thread 0x0000000017464000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002dd9eac method=fan.sys.ClassType.doReflect()V @ 111
Event: 54.412 Thread 0x0000000018e2c000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003383ca4 method=fan.folio3.Rec.updateDict(Lfan/haystack/Dict;Lfan/haystack/Dict;J)V @ 35
Event: 54.413 Thread 0x0000000018e2c000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003383ca4 method=fan.folio3.Rec.updateDict(Lfan/haystack/Dict;Lfan/haystack/Dict;J)V @ 35
Event: 54.435 Thread 0x000000001745f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000030586c8 method=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; @ 9
Event: 54.520 Thread 0x00000000177a2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036fbb70 method=fan.sys.Method$MethodFunc.checkArgs(IZZ)I @ 71
Event: 54.520 Thread 0x00000000177a2000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000288ae2c method=fan.sys.FanObj.toStr(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; @ 26
Event: 54.521 Thread 0x00000000177a2000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000030e176c method=fan.sys.FanObj.toStr(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; @ 26
Event: 54.521 Thread 0x00000000177a2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002e77708 method=fan.sys.MemBuf$MemBufOutStream.w(I)Lfan/sys/OutStream; @ 17
Event: 54.521 Thread 0x00000000177a2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000029ab7b8 method=fan.sys.FanObj.typeof(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lfan/sys/Type; @ 19
Event: 55.749 Thread 0x000000001745f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000033668a4 method=fan.sys.DateTime.compare(Ljava/lang/Object;)J @ 27

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 54.873 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f790d2a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 54.874 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f79301e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 54.874 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7932e98) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 54.875 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7938b00) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 54.875 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f793f110) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 55.888 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7f95308) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 55.888 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7fa25b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 55.889 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7fa5260) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 55.889 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7faaef0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 55.889 Thread 0x0000000019112800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000f7fb14e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u221\13320\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]

Events (10 events):
Event: 55.746 loading class fan/finWatcherExt/Wrap$List
Event: 55.746 loading class fan/finWatcherExt/Wrap$List done
Event: 55.749 Thread 0x000000001745f800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x00000000033668a4
Event: 55.749 Thread 0x000000001745f800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000033668a4 sp=0x000000002941ea90
Event: 55.749 Thread 0x000000001745f800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000253583b sp=0x000000002941ea18 mode 2
Event: 55.749 loading class fan/haystack/Ref
Event: 55.749 loading class fan/haystack/Ref done
Event: 55.751 loading class fan/skyarcd/SysLib
Event: 55.751 loading class fan/skyarcd/SysLib done
Event: 56.633 Thread 0x0000000017d49000 Thread added: 0x0000000017d49000


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff659730000 - 0x00007ff659767000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff8e3130000 - 0x00007ff8e3311000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff8e05c0000 - 0x00007ff8e0671000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff8dfaa0000 - 0x00007ff8dfd13000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff8db770000 - 0x00007ff8db7fb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ff864e30000 - 0x00007ff8652bf000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AcLayers.DLL
0x00007ff8e11b0000 - 0x00007ff8e124e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff8e2a30000 - 0x00007ff8e2bc0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff8df6e0000 - 0x00007ff8df700000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff8e06c0000 - 0x00007ff8e06e8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff8df900000 - 0x00007ff8dfa91000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff8df860000 - 0x00007ff8df8ff000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ff8df760000 - 0x00007ff8df858000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff8e13f0000 - 0x00007ff8e1441000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ff8e08e0000 - 0x00007ff8e0c01000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff8e0cc0000 - 0x00007ff8e0de4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff8dfd20000 - 0x00007ff8dfd99000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff8c5830000 - 0x00007ff8c58b5000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x00007ff8df4b0000 - 0x00007ff8df4c1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff8dc220000 - 0x00007ff8dc3d5000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
0x00007ff8e2940000 - 0x00007ff8e2a02000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ff8e0750000 - 0x00007ff8e07f9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ff8e0870000 - 0x00007ff8e08cb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff8dea00000 - 0x00007ff8dea38000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ff8def90000 - 0x00007ff8defb5000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x0000000000410000 - 0x0000000000413000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sfc.dll
0x00007ff8c58c0000 - 0x00007ff8c58d3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sfc_os.DLL
0x00007ff8e0680000 - 0x00007ff8e06ad000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ff8e0c10000 - 0x00007ff8e0cb1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff8cfec0000 - 0x00007ff8d0129000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17134.1006_none_d3fbb8f77c940c3f\COMCTL32.dll
0x0000000002200000 - 0x0000000002211000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\umppc8603.dll
0x0000000072b60000 - 0x0000000072c32000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000709b0000 - 0x0000000071255000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff8e08d0000 - 0x00007ff8e08d8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff8c7530000 - 0x00007ff8c7539000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff8e0800000 - 0x00007ff8e086c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff8da1a0000 - 0x00007ff8da1c3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff8cf230000 - 0x00007ff8cf23a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff8da170000 - 0x00007ff8da19a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff8dfe50000 - 0x00007ff8dfe99000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ff8caff0000 - 0x00007ff8cafff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ff8caf70000 - 0x00007ff8caf99000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007ff8caee0000 - 0x00007ff8caef6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff8e14f0000 - 0x00007ff8e2932000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff8dfea0000 - 0x00007ff8e05ae000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ff8df4d0000 - 0x00007ff8df4ef000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff8df450000 - 0x00007ff8df49c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff8df4a0000 - 0x00007ff8df4aa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL
0x00007ff8caec0000 - 0x00007ff8caeda000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ff8d1300000 - 0x00007ff8d14ca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
0x00007ff8d1680000 - 0x00007ff8d1927000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
0x00007ff8dee60000 - 0x00007ff8dee6b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
0x00007ff8decb0000 - 0x00007ff8ded16000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ff8c75d0000 - 0x00007ff8c75e6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll
0x00007ff8c75b0000 - 0x00007ff8c75ca000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00007ff8db870000 - 0x00007ff8db889000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x00007ff8dea90000 - 0x00007ff8deb4e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ff8e05b0000 - 0x00007ff8e05b8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ff8c75a0000 - 0x00007ff8c75ae000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x00007ff8d7300000 - 0x00007ff8d7315000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshbth.dll
0x00007ff8d2e90000 - 0x00007ff8d2e9a000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ff8da030000 - 0x00007ff8da0a2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ff8cae70000 - 0x00007ff8caeb8000     D:\UserData\z\Code\Git\gitlab\code\Stack\stack\lib\java\ext\host64.dll
0x00007ff8df4f0000 - 0x00007ff8df6d2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ff8df430000 - 0x00007ff8df442000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ff8e0e70000 - 0x00007ff8e0fc1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x00007ff8e1450000 - 0x00007ff8e14f0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ff8dee70000 - 0x00007ff8dee87000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ff8de630000 - 0x00007ff8de663000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ff8cae50000 - 0x00007ff8cae62000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ff8df330000 - 0x00007ff8df358000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ff8d9550000 - 0x00007ff8d9566000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ff8d9530000 - 0x00007ff8d954a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00007ff8aced0000 - 0x00007ff8acef4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x00007ff8cafe0000 - 0x00007ff8cafed000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\management.dll
0x00007ff8c5600000 - 0x00007ff8c564c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\pdh.dll
0x00007ff8c8ad0000 - 0x00007ff8c8adf000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\perfproc.dll
0x00007ff8c8ac0000 - 0x00007ff8c8ace000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\perfos.dll
0x00007ff8ad9b0000 - 0x00007ff8ad9f2000     C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1051149168\jna4172375217277385252.dll
0x00007ff864a60000 - 0x00007ff864b78000     D:\UserData\z\Code\DLL\srv.dll
0x00007ff864950000 - 0x00007ff864a54000     D:\UserData\z\Code\DLL\cli.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x000000018001f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\packet.dll
0x000000001cc60000 - 0x000000001ccc5000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wpcap.dll
0x00007ff8dd9d0000 - 0x00007ff8ddb99000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx512M -Dfan.home=D:\UserData\z\Code\Git\gitlab\code\Stack\stack 
java_command: fanx.tools.Fan finStackHost
java_class_path (initial): D:\UserData\z\Code\Git\gitlab\code\Stack\stack\lib\java\sys.jar;D:\UserData\z\Code\Git\gitlab\code\Stack\stack\lib\java\jline.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\bin\ia32;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;D:\UserData\z\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\UserData\z\Code\Git\gitlab\j2_code\Stack\stack\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Verint\Playback\;C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\z\AppData\Roaming\npm
USERNAME=z
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 17134 (10.0.17134.753)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 33393864k(18606096k free), swap 38374600k(19893212k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.221-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_221-b11), built on Jul  4 2019 04:39:29 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

**In another file I found:**

```
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x1b96f]
C  [AcLayers.DLL+0x7786]
C  [jna7224878983149948378.dll+0x1f738]
C  [jna7224878983149948378.dll+0x5b3d]
C  0x00000000030d8c67

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.jna.Native.free(J)V+0
j  com.sun.jna.Memory.free(J)V+7
j  com.sun.jna.Memory.dispose()V+4
j  com.sun.jna.Memory.finalize()V+1
J 3077 C1 java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Lsun/misc/JavaLangAccess;)V (62 bytes) @ 0x0000000003695d8c [0x0000000003695800+0x58c]
J 3076 C1 java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Ljava/lang/ref/Finalizer;Lsun/misc/JavaLangAccess;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x00000000036964dc [0x0000000003696480+0x5c]
j  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V+45
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Comment: We can't really do much here if we can't reproduce it: one suggestion, have you tried running your code on a newer JVM, like release 11?

Comment: No not tried yet, but how I can debug it? What should be steps for that?

Comment: This is fixed for. Actually in my case I was restarting the process and during that restart some callback was being processed. Which was crashing my application.