# JVM "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" crash in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, memory-leaks, jvm

[JVM Crash - "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406681/jvm-crash-exception-access-violation)

I made this CLI tool using Spring Boot and it takes a long time to run. I usually let it run overnight. Then, for several times I came across this JVM crash, and I don't know what to look for in there. I have seen other error reports on SO, but could not relate those to mine.

Can you please take a look at this log file? Bear in mind I have been having problems with memory leak in the app... I have started suffering from this error when I thought I had solved the memory leak.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000700000004, pid=14548, tid=0x000000000000514c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_172-b11) (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.172-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000700000004
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000011de000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000001780000,0x0000000001880000] [id=20812]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x0000000700000004 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX={method} {0x000000003555ae48} 'write' '(Ljava/io/DataOutputStream;)V' in 'javassist/bytecode/MethodInfo'
RBX=0x0000000000001ee1 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000007c0413390 is pointing into metadata
RDX=0x00000000012b8330 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000187f578 is an unknown value
RBP=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000012b8330 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000508e09810 is an oop

[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x0000000001780000,0x0000000001880000],  sp=0x000000000187f578,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000039300800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=12532, stack(0x000000005ce00000,0x000000005cf00000)]
  0x000000003943a800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1988, stack(0x000000005cd00000,0x000000005ce00000)]
  0x0000000036eda800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=7912, stack(0x000000005cc00000,0x000000005cd00000)]
  0x0000000031a7f800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=17516, stack(0x000000005cb00000,0x000000005cc00000)]
  0x0000000033c33000 JavaThread "children%0042y%004fbject%0054ype%0043ache.data" [_thread_blocked, id=11396, stack(0x0000000038c00000,0x0000000038d00000)]
  0x0000000033ff3000 JavaThread "Statistics Thread-__DEFAULT__-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6368, stack(0x0000000038a00000,0x0000000038b00000)]
  0x000000003419c800 JavaThread "rule%0047roup%0042y%004fbject%0054ype.data" [_thread_blocked, id=884, stack(0x0000000038900000,0x0000000038a00000)]
  0x0000000033dd1800 JavaThread "__DEFAULT__" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12260, stack(0x0000000038800000,0x0000000038900000)]
  0x0000000033b92800 JavaThread "HikariPool-1 housekeeper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19436, stack(0x0000000035200000,0x0000000035300000)]
  0x0000000031ad2000 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15508, stack(0x0000000032f30000,0x0000000033030000)]
  0x00000000319b4800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11136, stack(0x0000000032500000,0x0000000032600000)]
  0x00000000310b1800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18564, stack(0x0000000032400000,0x0000000032500000)]
  0x00000000318e5000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4264, stack(0x0000000032300000,0x0000000032400000)]
  0x00000000318de000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18968, stack(0x0000000032200000,0x0000000032300000)]
  0x00000000318dd000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14916, stack(0x0000000032100000,0x0000000032200000)]
  0x00000000318da800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17200, stack(0x0000000032000000,0x0000000032100000)]
  0x0000000030d3c000 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=440, stack(0x0000000031700000,0x0000000031800000)]
  0x0000000030d38800 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4040, stack(0x0000000031600000,0x0000000031700000)]
  0x0000000030d2c800 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16656, stack(0x0000000031500000,0x0000000031600000)]
  0x0000000030d21800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15880, stack(0x0000000031400000,0x0000000031500000)]
  0x0000000030d20800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14800, 

Other Threads:
  0x000000002ee09800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000030af0000,0x0000000030bf0000] [id=14120]
  0x00000000319c6800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000032b30000,0x0000000032c30000] [id=20780]

=>0x00000000011de000 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000001780000,0x0000000001880000] [id=20812]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000011c3e10] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x000000002ee09800
[0x00000000011c6720] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x000000003943a800

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 1398784K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 0% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8388444K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 99% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006bffd72f8,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012410000,0x0000000013c20000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000fe10000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006d2d3c10
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000014c20000, 0x0000000020c20000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000020c20000, 0x000000002cc20000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000520000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1297Kb max_used=1297Kb free=244462Kb
 bounds [0x0000000003410000, 0x0000000003680000, 0x0000000012410000]
 total_blobs=681 nmethods=103 adapters=500
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (0 events):
No events

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 9954.692 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=444 (full 16):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 717783K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 51% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007967f5e10,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000,0x000000076ab00000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 7924048K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 94% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006a3a54310,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51703K, capacity 55306K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7412K, capacity 7964K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 9993.817 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=445 (full 16):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 2116567K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 51% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007967f5e10,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000,0x000000076ab00000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 7924048K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 94% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006a3a54310,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51703K, capacity 55306K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7412K, capacity 7964K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 9994.103 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=445 (full 16):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 787939K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 56% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000745778c30,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8113726K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 96% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006af38fb30,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51703K, capacity 55306K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7412K, capacity 7964K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 9994.103 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=446 (full 17):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 787939K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 56% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000745778c30,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8113726K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 96% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006af38fb30,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51703K, capacity 55306K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7412K, capacity 7964K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 10004.003 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=446 (full 17):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 462817K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 33% used [0x0000000715600000,0x00000007319f8440,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8388288K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 99% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006bffb0050,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 10069.392 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=447 (full 18):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 1861601K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 33% used [0x0000000715600000,0x00000007319f8440,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8388288K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 99% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006bffb0050,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 10079.333 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=447 (full 18):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 467899K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 33% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006dc8eefb0,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 0% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8388496K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 99% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006bffe4008,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 10122.711 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=448 (full 19):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 1398784K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 0% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8388496K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 99% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006bffe4008,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 10133.349 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=448 (full 19):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 529880K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 37% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006e05761c0,0x0000000715600000)
  from space 1397760K, 0% used [0x0000000715600000,0x0000000715600000,0x000000076ab00000)
  to   space 1397760K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 8388608K, used 8388444K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000)
  object space 8388608K, 99% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x00000006bffd72f8,0x00000006c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 10184.884 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=449 (full 20):
 PSYoungGen      total 2796544K, used 1398784K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1398784K, 100% used
 Metaspace       used 51654K, capacity 55228K, committed 55936K, reserved 1097728K
  class space    used 7405K, capacity 7951K, committed 8064K, reserved 1048576K

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 10181.675 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 73> (0x00000007114fe3a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.694 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 68> (0x0000000711531bb8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.700 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 68> (0x00000007115406a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.725 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 68> (0x000000071157a7c0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.729 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 77> (0x0000000711586b88) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.731 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 73> (0x000000071158b070) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.735 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 37> (0x00000007115945c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.736 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 6> (0x0000000711597870) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.736 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 73> (0x00000007115990a8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 10181.750 Thread 0x000000003943a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 68> (0x00000007115b91e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u172\10810\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]

Events (10 events):
Event: 10184.822 loading class java/util done
Event: 10184.836 loading class java/util/Object
Event: 10184.836 loading class java/util/Object done
Event: 10184.837 loading class java/util
Event: 10184.837 loading class java/util done
Event: 10184.844 loading class java/util/String
Event: 10184.844 loading class java/util/String done
Event: 10184.846 loading class java/util
Event: 10184.846 loading class java/util done
Event: 10184.884 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff76a600000 - 0x00007ff76a637000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffaf6db0000 - 0x00007ffaf6f9d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffaf5b90000 - 0x00007ffaf5c43000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffaf3190000 - 0x00007ffaf3423000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffaf5c50000 - 0x00007ffaf5cf3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffaf67e0000 - 0x00007ffaf687e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffaf6920000 - 0x00007ffaf69be000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffaf5dd0000 - 0x00007ffaf5ef2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffaf61b0000 - 0x00007ffaf6347000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffaf3110000 - 0x00007ffaf3130000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffaf68f0000 - 0x00007ffaf6919000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffaf2f70000 - 0x00007ffaf3109000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffaf3cb0000 - 0x00007ffaf3d50000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffaf2e70000 - 0x00007ffaf2f6a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffaee310000 - 0x00007ffaee589000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.719_none_05b84458071c8757\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffaf5850000 - 0x00007ffaf5b7c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffaf3f50000 - 0x00007ffaf3fce000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffaf56f0000 - 0x00007ffaf571e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x000000006dc70000 - 0x000000006dd42000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006cab0000 - 0x000000006d353000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffaf5b80000 - 0x00007ffaf5b88000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffaee680000 - 0x00007ffaee6a4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffaee590000 - 0x00007ffaee5bd000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffaf3460000 - 0x00007ffaf34aa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffaef4b0000 - 0x00007ffaef4ba000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffad40e0000 - 0x00007ffad40e9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffaf6880000 - 0x00007ffaf68ed000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x000000006dc60000 - 0x000000006dc6f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006dc30000 - 0x000000006dc59000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006e8e0000 - 0x000000006e915000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x000000006e8d0000 - 0x000000006e8d8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\npt.dll
0x000000006e8a0000 - 0x000000006e8c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x000000006dc10000 - 0x000000006dc26000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffaf41f0000 - 0x00007ffaf56e2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffaf57a0000 - 0x00007ffaf5848000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffaf34b0000 - 0x00007ffaf3bfa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffaf2e40000 - 0x00007ffaf2e64000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffaf2de0000 - 0x00007ffaf2e3d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffaf69c0000 - 0x00007ffaf6a12000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffaf2dc0000 - 0x00007ffaf2dd1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffaf3f30000 - 0x00007ffaf3f47000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cryptsp.dll
0x000000006e890000 - 0x000000006e899000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x00007ffaf2610000 - 0x00007ffaf2677000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000000006dbf0000 - 0x000000006dc0a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffaf2370000 - 0x00007ffaf2436000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ffaf6d10000 - 0x00007ffaf6d18000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffaf2330000 - 0x00007ffaf236d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000000006e220000 - 0x000000006e246000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x00007ffaeb200000 - 0x00007ffaeb20a000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ffaefd70000 - 0x00007ffaefde9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ffaf3430000 - 0x00007ffaf3456000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
0x000000006dbc0000 - 0x000000006dbcd000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000000006dbd0000 - 0x000000006dbe1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ffaf2190000 - 0x00007ffaf21c3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffaf2ca0000 - 0x00007ffaf2cc8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffaf27e0000 - 0x00007ffaf27ec000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00007ffaefd30000 - 0x00007ffaefd46000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffaefd10000 - 0x00007ffaefd2c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00007ffae8ac0000 - 0x00007ffae8ad6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll
0x00007ffae88c0000 - 0x00007ffae88da000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00007ffae7bd0000 - 0x00007ffae7bde000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x00007ffaef950000 - 0x00007ffaef96b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x00007ffae7790000 - 0x00007ffae77a5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wshbth.dll
0x00007ffae33d0000 - 0x00007ffae35bd000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:61805,suspend=y,server=n -Xms1g -Xmx12g -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Xverify:none -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\Users\robaina\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: net.weg.maestro.TranspilerApp
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\robaina\Documents\Spring projects\Maestro 4.0\maestro-4-0\transpiler\target\classes;C:\java\m2\repository\net\lingala\zip4j\zip4j\2.2.2\zip4j-2.2.2.jar;C:\java\m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.21\byte-buddy-1.8.21.jar;C:\java\m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\java\m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\java\m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.4.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\java\m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
PATH=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\jbr\\bin\server;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\support2\product\11.1.0\client_2\bin;C:\app\support\Oracle_11\bin;C:\Oracle11\bin;C:\Oracle11_64\bin;C:\Oracle11_32\bin;C:\Oracle\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Program Files\SolidWorks 2015\eDrawings X64 Edition;C:\Program Files\SolidWorks 2016\eDrawings;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\java\apache-cxf-3.2.5\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\robaina\Documents\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Users\robaina\bin\Sencha\Cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Users\robaina\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\robaina\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\robaina\bin\Sencha\Cmd;C:\Users\robaina\Documents\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\bin;;C:\Users\robaina\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
USERNAME=robaina
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.475)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 16730672k(666680k free), swap 58630416k(34683648k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.172-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_172-b11), built on Mar 28 2018 21:21:52 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Nov 13 19:43:00 2019
elapsed time: 10185 seconds (0d 2h 49m 45s)
```

It was pointed out by @apangin that byte code verification was disabled for the JVM, and it is possibly causing crashes. I noticed that this option disabled it in IntelliJ. I will try running the application without this option once again.

[image: IntelliJ option for noverify]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JVM Crash - "EXCEPTION\_ACCESS\_VIOLATION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406681/jvm-crash-exception-access-violation)

Comment: The accepted answer on the referenced question was related to a DirectX library, which has nothing to do with my app (unless there is something weird going on). Also, the answer does not inform how the error dll was found in the log file. I took a look at that answer and it did not help much...

Comment: You disabled bytecode verification by `-Xverify:none` and thus made JVM vulnerable to invalid bytecode. With the verification disabled, JVM can behave unpredictably, including crashes like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if). [Never disable bytecode verification in production](https://blogs.oracle.com/buck/never-disable-bytecode-verification-in-a-production-system).

Comment: I have edited the question. I will try running the app without that parameter.

Comment: You may want to try to update your Java version to a more recent version, 1.8.0_172 is relatively old. It might also be a problem with the bytecode manipulation done by javassist.

Comment: Thank you @apangin. My app now ran without any problems. Would you mind answering the question so that I can reward you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the crash log I noticed `-Xverify:none` among JVM options. Turning off bytecode verification makes JVM vulnerable to invalid bytecode. With the verification disabled, JVM can behave unpredictably, including crashes like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if).

The crash log has also a sign of bytecode instrumentation library `javassist`. In theory, the invalid bytecode instrumentation along with the disabled verification can be a reason of JVM crashes.