# Strange JVM Crash

Tags: java

A while ago I opened up my computer to work on a Minecraft mod I had been working on, but instead of running like normal, I got this exception:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffbb88537e0, pid=18248, tid=9400
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.4.1+1 (17.0.4.1+1) (build 17.0.4.1+1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.4.1+1 (17.0.4.1+1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x1937e0]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Name\Desktop\SurvivalSnacks\run\hs_err_pid18248.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

After trying to find out what was happening for a few hours, I realized it wasn't a problem with my code. I tried running other java programs I had made. A simple Hello World program worked, but my LWJGL game crashed with the same exception, and any program that I used file IO crashed with File Not Found. The IO program also worked for other people that were working on the same project through GitHub.

The log from IntelliJ is too long to post in the question, so I used some website that posts text: https://jpst.it/2-biQ

Some things I tried:
Reinstalling IntelliJ
Reinstalling JDK
Running IntelliJ as admin
Factory Resetting my PC

All of the above things resulted in the same error

I also found this Stack overflow with a very similar problem to mine, but the solution did not work for me.
[JVM Crash - "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406681/jvm-crash-exception-access-violation)

Comment: Are you using an AMD graphics card? If so [this post (`community.amd.com`)](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amd-driver-conflicts-with-java-and-causes-crash-atio6axx-dll/td-p/193499) might be related.

Comment: In general these things are difficult to track down.  The JVM has crashed when calling native code.  So it's possible that either the JVM is calling the native code wrong or that there is a bug in, for example, a recently updated driver on your machine.  I'd start with getting the newest Temurin JDK (17.0.5+8 as of this writing) to see if it helps.  Then I'd update everything you can on the machine.  The frustrating part is that it may or may not help.

Comment: Might be useful to add the `windows` tag given that yours and the referenced question also have that in common.

Comment: Did you have a look at the contents of `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\SurvivalSnacks\run\hs_err_pid18248.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going to my graphics card company and downloading a version from before the error started happening. Just rolling back didn’t work because rolling back only let me go back one version, I had to go back to an update from 5 months ago.